# Python - Function not defined

Tags: python, function

In python, I'm trying to make an RPG and when I do "def townbar():" it says that it's not defined.

This code is for reference to make sure that everything is making sense:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.health2 = 100
        self.health = self.health2
        self.attack = 10

# Game
def main():
    print("Welcome player.")
    print("1. Start")
    print("2. Load")
    print("3. Exit")
    option = input("> ")
    if option == "1":
        start()
    elif option == "2":
        pass
    elif option == "3":
        sys.exit()
    else:
        main()

def start():
    print('\n' * 80)
    print("Hello, what is your name?")
    option = input("> ")
    global PlayerIG
    PlayerIG = Player(option)
    start1()

def start1():
    print('\n' * 80)
    print("Name: %s" % PlayerIG.name)
    print("Attack: %i" % PlayerIG.attack)
    print("Health: %i/%i\n" % (PlayerIG.health, PlayerIG.health2))
    print("1. Go to nearby town")
    print("2. Stand here and do nothing")
    option = input("> ")
    if option == "1":
        town()
    if option == "2":
        print("Really? This is the guy we chose to be the hero of this story? 
    *sigh* Pick again.")
        start1()
    else:
        start1()

def town():
    print('\n' * 80)
    print("You arrive at the town and you see 3 signs.\n")
    print("1. Go to the bar")
    print("2. Go to the market")
    print("3. Go to the king")
    option = input("> ")
    if option == "1":
        townbar()
    elif option == "2":
        market()
    elif option == "3":
        print("The king ignores you, as you are but a peasant\n")
        town()
    else:
        town()
```

This is the part that gives me problems, it says that bar is not defined (it was the old name for townbar). After I changed the name and checked that everything was fine, it still shows that error.

```
def townbar():
    print('\n' * 80)
    print("You see many people in the bar.")
    print("1. Talk to the bartender")
    print("2. Talk to the people in the bar")
    print("3. Exit the bar")
    option = input("> ")
    if option == "1":
        print("The bartender greets you.\n")
        bartendertalk()
    elif option == "2":
        print("The people don't care enough or are too drunk to speak to 
    you.\n")
        townbar()
    elif option == "3":
        town()
    else:
        townbar()

def bartendertalk():
    print('\n' * 80)
    print("Would you like to hear of the local news? [Y/N]")
    option = input("> ")
    if option == "Y":
        print("Would you like to hear the gossip or some real news?\n")
        print("1. Gossip")
        print("2. Real news")
        option2 = input("> ")
        if option2 == "1":
            print("I've heard that Ron has been cheating on Margaret with 
                  Beatrice! Very sad.\n")
            bartendertalk()
        elif option2 == "2":
            print("People talk of a destroyed castle holding centuries worth 
                   of gold in there, but nobody has ever explored it.")
            bartendertalk()
    if option == "N":
        print("Then why are you talking to me?\n")
        townbar()
    else:
        bartendertalk()

main()
```

Error:

```
 File "C:\Users\Leo\Documents\Loadingscreens\PyCharm Community Edition 
 2017.3.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1668, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Leo\Documents\Loadingscreens\PyCharm Community Edition 
2017.3.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1662, in main
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "C:\Users\Leo\Documents\Loadingscreens\PyCharm Community Edition 
2017.3.2\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1072, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Users\Leo\Documents\Loadingscreens\PyCharm Community Edition 
2017.3.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/Leo/PycharmProjects/RPG Project/Game File.py", line 63, in 
<module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/Leo/PycharmProjects/RPG Project/Game File.py", line 21, in 
 main
    start()
  File "C:/Users/Leo/PycharmProjects/RPG Project/Game File.py", line 35, in 
start
    start1()
  File "C:/Users/Leo/PycharmProjects/RPG Project/Game File.py", line 46, in 
start1
    town()
  File "C:/Users/Leo/PycharmProjects/RPG Project/Game File.py", line 57, in 
town
    bar()
NameError: name 'bar' is not defined
```

Comment: Show us the stacktrace. And format your code properly.

Comment: Beautiful code - now please go ahead and format it correctly. The easy way to do this is to change your indentation to spaces, copy it to here and use the **{}**  format on it. Currently the codeindentation is messed up and thats important for python.

Comment: @PatrickArtner There is an easier way, which I submitted as an edit suggestion on his behalf, namely unindent the function definitions and then reindent everything using the curly braces.

Comment: Just to note - you're getting into bad practices here... If you want to repeat prompting users for options then use a loop - calling the function again within the function is called recursion and while unlikely, if the user keeps making choices that do that - you'll eventually blow the stack. Not to mention it's completely unnecessary :)

Comment: @ubadub Sure. But do YOU know if his code really looks like how you fixed it? I could go to the trouble of fixing his indentations myself - but - that might vanish his error ;o)

Comment: @ubadub be careful with edits fixing indentation. It can possibly be hiding the source of errors and also - you missed indentation inside the class and indented a function within another function in that edit...

Comment: How would I use a loop? I'm new to Python, thank you for your patience. I also don't know what a stacktrace is, please explain.

Comment: Stacktrace is the output of an "error" when you try to run your python program. This stacktrace contains useful insights about what went wrong, where the error is and the type of error. If you are about to fix a problem in your program you have to read the stacktrace and make sense of "why" your program is failing.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to your question .. and hence will get some downvotes before I remove it again ;o) but if you decide on using this kind of menu all over the place you should consider packing the functionality into its on function like so:

```
def choicer(choices, onErrorMessage): 
    '''Uses a dict of choices to present a menue. 
The menuChoice with key -1 is used as flavour text before 
first input occures, the onErrorMessage (or if None the -1 option
is used for consecutive inputs after illegan user choice. 
It returns the key of the option choosen.'''

    def flavourTextOnInput():
        '''print flavour text if present'''
        if -1 in choices.keys(): # print flavour text if given:
            print(choices[-1])

    def printMenu():
        ''' print all choices without key -1'''
        for key in choices: 
            if  key != -1:  
                print(key, '. ', choices[key])

    def inputNumber(): 
        '''ask for input, convert to int else return None'''
        num = None
        numText = input()
        try:
            num = int(numText)
        except:
            pass

        return num

    flavourTextOnInput()
    printMenu()

    c = inputNumber()
    while(c not in choices.keys()):
        if onErrorMessage:
            print(onErrorMessage)
        else:
            flavourTextOnInput() 
        c = inputNumber()

    return c
```

And use it like this:

```
retVal = choicer({-1: "Howdy - what do you like to do?",   # spezial by definition
                   1: "drink beer", 
                   2: "drink whisky", 
                   3: "get drunk by rum", 
                   4: "hit some patron"},                  # set of choices
                  "What'cha want? Too loud - not heard correctly") # onErrorMessage
# then you can handle retVar to your liking
```

You supply a dictionary with choices and a error message. The dict key `-1` is special, it is printed as flavour text before the first input(). The `onErrorMessage`  is printed every time a wrong input is done. The function returns the integer key of the option that was choosen and will repeat until a valid option is inputted.

You should do an far easier function just for Y/N answers which takes a string as qestion and loops until the answer is either Y or N. Your main program will get less complicated that way and its easier to keep track of everything that is going on - preventing errors by reusing failproof functionality.

```
def yesNo(text):
    '''Prints text once and repeats input until first non space character
is nN or yY - returns a True if yY else False. Ignores all other inputs
then the first non space one'''
    print(text, " [Y/N]")

    c = None
    while (c not in ['Y','N']):
        c = (input().strip()[0].upper()) # use 1st non space upper case character as input
    return c == "Y" # else False
```

Usage:

```
if yesNo("Quit now?"): # please rename the functions, naming is hackish
    print("Quitting")
else:
    print("continuing")
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `townbar()` is a function outside the class, then put it above the caller i.e `town()`. This should be the reason why it is saying function not defined. The callee should be defined before the caller.